# Can't use paramaters in HP Loadrunner 11

Tags: c, loadrunner

I have the following code:

```
lr_output_message( "We are on iteration #%s", lr_eval_string( "{iteration}" ) );
```

Return log message:

> We are on iteration #{iteration}

Did anyone have the same poblem?
A few hours ago, it was works fine.

Comment: Have you deleted something such as `lr_save_int(a,"iteration");`? I got that from here: http://www.loadrunnerz.com/2014/05/lr-eval-string-function-in-loadrunner-with-examples.html

Comment: No. I run exemple, from link and just get : Action.c(74): {IntegerValue}

Comment: better formatting and fixed grammar. Please visit [ask].

Comment: Asking the foundation question, has the parameter "iteration" been created and configured to contain the iteration value?

Comment: Yes. Paramater was been created.

Answer (score 1):

The only time you'll see an output like that is if LoadRunner can't find a parameter with that precise name.

Usually this is because you've done something wrong; a typo, etc.

Did you define "iteration" EXACTLY like you are using it?  Or did you do something like use a capital 'I' (Iteration), or spell it differently, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
lr_output_message( "We are on iteration # %d", atoi(lr_eval_string("{iterationnumber}")));
```

Comment: Hi! Thx for answer. if i use 'atoi' =>  "We are on iteration (null)"

Comment: paste your code here and copy my code to ur script and just change the parameter iterationnumber to the name whichever you want it works fine.